# PHP AWS SDK generating invalid presigned URL

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This PHP function generates a S3 pre-signed URL:

```php
public function generatePreSignedUrl(): string
    {
        $secretAccessKey = urlencode(env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'));
        $bucket = env('AWS_BUCKET');
        $client = new S3Client([
            'version' => 'latest',
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'credentials' => [
                'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
                'secret' => $secretAccessKey,
            ],
        ]);

        $expires = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(15)->timestamp;

        $keyname = 'video.mp4';
        
        $command = $client->getCommand('PutObject', [
            'Bucket' => $bucket,
            'Key' => $keyname,
            'ContentType' => 'video/mp4',
        ]);

        $request = $client->createPresignedRequest($command, $expires);
        return (string) $request->getUri();
    }
```

But, when I try to use the generated URL, I get the following error:

```xml
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.
Check your key and signing method.</Message
```

Comment: Why do you need to urlencode secret key?

Comment: @HùngNguyễn it contains some characters like "/" and "+"

Answer (score 0):

No need to encode the secret key— that's done when the request is signed.